# Scala, why when I pass a lambda function as argument to another function i cannot execute it

Tags: scala, function, lambda

I am trying to create a concurrent method that saves in two different variables the result of two blocks of code task1 and task2:

```scala
def parallel[A, B](fun_a: => A, fun_b: => B): (A, B) = {
    var res_a: A = 1.asInstanceOf[A]
    var res_b: B = 1.asInstanceOf[B]

    val hilo = new Thread {
      override def run(): Unit = {
        res_a = fun_a
      }
    }
    val hilo1 = new Thread() {
      override def run(): Unit = {
        res_b = fun_b
      }
    }
    hilo.start()
    hilo1.start()
    
    hilo.join()
    hilo1.join()

    (res_a, res_b)
  }

  val task1 = {3+4}
  val task2 = {3*1}
  println(parallel(task1, task2))
```

This is the correct answer in theory but I do not understand if val task1/task2 are functions or just the result of the block inside brackets. I tried to edit the method parallel to accept only generic values:

```scala
def parallel[A, B](fun_a: A, fun_b: B): (A, B)
```

and it still works fine. In this case,  The computation of task1 and task2 is made before they pass as parameter to the function, or is made when the result is assigned to the variables res_a, res_b in each thread?

I tried to pass task1 and task2 as a method, it works fine but when I pass it as function, in the variable is saved the serialization of the function.

```scala
  def task1():Int = {3+4} //method
  val task2: Int => Int = (x:Int) => {3*x} //anonymous function
  println(parallel(task1, task2))
```

i changed the code so the anonymous function gets executed but now i get an exception:

```scala
def parallel[A, B](fun_a: => A, fun_b: => B): (A, B) = {
    var res_a: A = 1.asInstanceOf[A]
    var res_b: B = 1.asInstanceOf[B]

    val hilo = new Thread {
      override def run(): Unit = {
        res_a = fun_a
      }
    }
    val hilo1 = new Thread() {
      override def run(): Unit = {
        res_b = fun_b(3) // here, because i think this is a function {val task2: Int => Int = (x:Int) => {3*x} i try to pass its argument
      }
    }
    hilo.start()
    hilo1.start()
    
    hilo.join()
    hilo1.join()

    (res_a, res_b)
  }
```

it says that B does not take parameters but i defined it before as a lambda that takes one parameter.

I do not understand why i defined the method as one that takes as arguments two functions but it does not let me pass arguments to that functions

Answer (score 1):

The following code works:

```scala
def parallel[A, B](fun_a: => A, fun_b: Int => B): (A, B) = {
  var res_a: A = 1.asInstanceOf[A]
  var res_b: B = 1.asInstanceOf[B]

  val hilo = new Thread {
    override def run(): Unit = {
      res_a = fun_a
    }
  }
  val hilo1 = new Thread() {
    override def run(): Unit = {
      res_b = fun_b(3)
    }
  }
  hilo.start()
  hilo1.start()

  hilo.join()
  hilo1.join()

  (res_a, res_b)
}

println(
  parallel(
    { 3 * 3 }, 
    (x: Int) => { 3 + x }
  )
)
```

Note how the type declaration of `fun_b` is changed to `fun_b: Int => B`. In this case, `fun_a` doesn't do much, though.

And admittedly, the generic type doesn't make much sense, if `Int` is hard coded in there. So a more sensible solution would be something like this:

```scala
def parallel[A, B](fun_a: A => A, fun_b: B => B, a: A, b: B): (A, B) = {
  var res_a: A = 1.asInstanceOf[A]
  var res_b: B = 1.asInstanceOf[B]

  val hilo = new Thread {
    override def run(): Unit = {
      res_a = fun_a(a)
    }
  }
  val hilo1 = new Thread() {
    override def run(): Unit = {
      res_b = fun_b(b)
    }
  }
  hilo.start()
  hilo1.start()

  hilo.join()
  hilo1.join()

  (res_a, res_b)
}

println(
  parallel(
    (y: Int) => { y * 3 },
    (x: Int) => { x + 3 },
    3,
    3
  )
)

println(
  parallel(
    (y: Int) =>    { y * 3 },
    (x: String) => { x + 3 },
    3,
    "3"
  )
)

println(
  parallel(
    (y: String) => { y * 3 },
    (x: Int) =>    { x + 3 },
    "3",
    3
  )
)
```

This will print:

```
(9,6)
(9,33)
(333,6)
```